# Get version of a file from before git pull

Tags: git, github

I'm, not sure if this is possible, but I would like to knwo what version of a file I had before I did a git pull.

For example

1. I had a set of files which had been deployed to production by git pulling them from github, which weren't behaving as I expected.
2. I added some logging from my local machine and committed this to github.
3. I did a git pull to get the new logging
4. My code inexplicably worked, which makes me think the deployed version had not been updated to the latest version before my pull.

I want to check which version was deployed before I did the git pull in step 3. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: For future - create tags for each version ready to production.

Comment: @kan I've just implemented doing so this morning since this came up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, we start with this: `git pull` is basically `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, if you've configured it or run it differently, `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`).

The `git fetch` command updates only "remote branch" labels, not local ones, so we get to ignore that part, and thus ask: "after a `git merge`, how can I tell which revision a branch-label *used* to name, or which revision `HEAD` named before?"  The answer—well, one of several, but let's use this one—is: "it's in your reflogs".

Git keeps a "ref log" for branch-names, and also a ref-log for `HEAD` itself.  When `git merge` succeeds and updates both a branch-name and `HEAD`, the corresponding reflogs are updated with the old-and-new commit IDs as needed.

If you've done some other `git checkout`s and so on, `HEAD`'s reflog may have been updated more since then.  The branch's, however, is only updated when the branch label itself is updated, so it's very likely that the first step backwards in history will tell you where the branch was before the successful merge updated it.

You don't say what the *name* of your branch is here, so I'll just call it `sasquatch`.  The place `sasquatch` pointed one step ago is simply `sasquatch@{1}`.

You can see the raw commit-ID with:

```
git rev-parse sasquatch@{1}
```

for instance, or supply that name to `git log` or `git show`.

The second step back is `sasquatch@{2}`, and so on.

In a few cases, you must use quotes or backslashes to protect the curly brace characters `{` and `}` from hungry shells that like to eat them, so you might need to write:

```
git rev-parse 'sasquatch@{1}'
```

if the version without the quotes errors-out.

You can see all the reflog entries for branch `sasquatch` with:

```
git reflog sasquatch
```

Without an argument, `git reflog` shows you all the entries for `HEAD`.

---

Just for completeness, let's also note here that `git merge` leaves `ORIG_HEAD` pointing to the commit-ID from before the merge.  This name is good until something else overwrites it, such as a rebase or another merge.  However, the reflog names are good for quite a while (although as you accumulate more changes the numbers increment).

---

All of this tells you about your *local* repository.  You may also have reflogs for `origin/` remote-branches; these will tell you what you (or your git) observed when it contacted `origin` and got updates.  They cannot tell you what was actually in place at various times on a remote, except for those times when your git called up theirs and got updates (snapshots in time, as it were).